# Accessing data returned by a koala friends connection

Tags: hash, koala

So, I'm trying to grab just the names of a user's friends using Koala:

```
        @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(self.authentication_token)
        @graph.get_connections("me", "friends").each do |friend|
            puts friend['name']
        end
```

However, this puts out the entirety of the hash, ala:

```
{"name"=>"Tad Luedtke", "id"=>"17212478"}, {"name"=>"Harrison Hoffman", "id"=>"17212694"}, {"name"=>"Greg Nelson", "id"=>"17212720"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I dont see the problem, the same code returned me a friend list.

Answer (score 1):

Am I correct to assume you're doing this in the console? Try scrolling up. After it's done with the execution of your code block, it outputs the entire hash, which if you have more than a few friends, is very large, so you have to scroll up to see the puts statements. I just did this in the rails console and it worked.

If you are using the rails console and want to disable that (shut IRB up), try the command

```
conf.echo = false
```

Then run your code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert these hash first to array ,,you can do that simply try these code

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(self.authentication_token)
@friends =@graph.get_connections("me", "friends").to_a
@friends.each do |friend|
puts friend["name"]
end
```